# C++ Overriding hash<T> for derived classes of T

Tags: c++, hash

Couple of questions/issues:

1. The code below isn't compiling (see comments below)
2. Would I have to override the hash function for Bar and Baz too if I wanted them to return id() as their hash value?

```
#include <functional>

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(short id);
  short id() const;
private:
  const short id_;
};

class Bar : public Foo {};

class Baz : public Foo {};

Foo::Foo(short id) :
id_(id)
{}

short Foo::id() const
{
  return id_;
}

namespace std
{
  template <> struct hash<Foo> //hash is not a class template
  { //explicit specialization of non-template std::hash
    size_t operator()(const Foo& foo) const
    {
      return hash<short>()(foo.id()); //std::hash is not a template
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: `Foo::id()` needs to be declared `const`.

Comment: There's no overriding happening here.

Comment: You sure have to specialize `std::hash` for all types for which it shall have special behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a `const` reference is being passed to `hash::operator()` but `Foo::id()` is not declared `const`. This prevents you from calling `id()` on any `const` instance of `Foo`. To fix this just declare the function `const` like so

```
class Foo
{
public:
    short id() const;
};
```

If you are defining an instance of `std::hash` and passing one of the derived classes as the template argument you will need to provide a specialization for each one. If you are simply passing an instance of a derived class to `std::hash<Foo>` you do not need to provide specializations for them.

Also make sure you are using a C++11 compiler (with C++11 mode enabled if necessary) and are including the `<functional>` header as mentioned by Kerrek in the comments.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious I did that as well, still not compiling.

Comment: @Deduplicator What do you mean by "not converted"? Are you saying I have to write std::hash<Bar> and std::hash<Baz> too?

Comment: @AgrimPathak I updated my answer based on the Deduplicators comments to clarify what I was referring to.

Comment: C++11 was the remaining issue.  Can you please also clarify the "If you are defining" paragraph.  Are you saying I have to either write std::hash<Foo> OR std::hash<Bar> and std::hash<Baz>?  Thanks.

Comment: If you only need to call `id()` to get the hash data you can use only `std::hash<Foo>`. In this case any time you try to hash an instance of `Baz` an implicit conversion is applied (no-op in this case) and it is passed to the `hash<Foo>`'s function operator.